# virtualenv couldn't find python interpreter path?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

my computer have python3.4, python3.5, python3.6, python3.7, but now i want to use python virtualenv to create a env , but it show path not found?

---

The image in here:
[image: '']

Comment: git-bash command line not work, use system cmd instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to Python, for example:

```
virtualenv.exe -p C:\Python37\python.exe
```

For git-bash the command should be slightly different:

```
virtualenv.exe -p /c/Python37/python.exe
```

Comment: i use github cmd line it is not work, i use windows system cmd it work ok.

Comment: For git-bash the command should be slightly different. I extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all having multiple versions of Python is not advised especially if you cant manage them. The issue you are getting stems from the installation of the Virtualenv package. You need to use the python version that has Virtualenv in the site-packages. Examine all the site packages for the 3 versions then use the one that has virtualenv alternatively you can uninstall all the 3 versions and reinstall one I'd advise on Python 3.6 then install virtualenv via pip and try again.

Comment: my app need to run at different environment and i do't want to uninstall other python's version for i need to use them for some reaseon.

Comment: Then check in the site-packages which version has virtualenv installed and use that

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you remember to mark it as the correct answer.